# resolution tautological sheaf projective dual $G(3,6)$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, grassmannians, projective-resolution

I consider the Plücker embedding of $G(3,6)$ in $\mathbb{P}^{19}$. I denote by $X \subset {\mathbb{P}^{19}}^*$ the projective dual to $G(3,6) \subset \mathbb{P}^{19}$. The variety $X$ is a quartic hypersurface. Let us consider the conormal diagram:

$$ G(3,6) \stackrel{q}\longleftarrow \mathbb{P}(N_{G(3,6)/\mathbb{P}^{19}}(-1)) \stackrel{p}\longrightarrow X$$

Let me denote by $\mathcal{R}$ the tautological bundle on $G(3,6)$. The sheaf $p_* q^* \mathcal{R}$ is generically of rank $3$ on $X$. I was wondering if a locally free resolution of this sheaf as **a sheaf on ${\mathbb{P}^{19}}^*$** was known.

Let me give an easier example where the resolution of such a sheaf is well-known and easy to construct.

Consider the Plücker embedding $G(2,8) \subset \mathbb{P}^{27}$. I denote by $Y$ the projective dual to $G(2,8)$ (this is again a quartic hypersurface). Let us consider again the conormal diagram:

$$ G(2,8) \stackrel{q}\longleftarrow \mathbb{P}(N_{G(2,8)/\mathbb{P}^{27}}(-1)) \stackrel{p}\longrightarrow Y$$

The sheaf $p_* q^* \mathcal{R}$ is generically of rank $2$ on $Y$ and we have a resolution of $p_* q^* \mathcal{R}$ as a sheaf on $\mathbb{P}^{27}$ which is given as follows:

$$ 0 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^8 \otimes \mathcal{0}_{\mathbb{P}^{27}}(-1) \stackrel{A}\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}^8 \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{27}} \rightarrow p_*q^* \mathcal{R} \rightarrow 0,$$
where $A$ is a $8 \times 8$ skew-symmetric matrices with linear entries.

In the $G(3,6)$ case, I would like to know if a resolution (in the spirit of that for $G(2,8)$) of $p_*q^* \mathcal{R}$ is known.

thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try to compute it? It is a direct but lengthy Borel--Bott--Weil calculation.

Comment: @Sasha : In fact I haven't tried direct computations. I am not skilled enough with BBW to do that. I have the feeling the resolution should be given by a generic "skew map" (whatever that means) from $\bigwedge^2 \mathbb{C}^6$ to $\mathbb{C}^6$.

Comment: But I don't know if the cokernel of such a map will be generically of rank $0$, then will jump to rank $3$ on the quartic and then...?????

Comment: The map $\Lambda^2V \otimes O(-1) \to V^\vee \otimes O$ on $P(\Lambda^3V^\vee)$ is surjective at the open orbit of $X$ (this is easy to see, because a general point of $X$ looks as $x_{124} - x_{135} + x_{236}$, and its convolutions with bivectors generate $V^\vee$). Furthermore, at the next orbit (with general point $x_{123} + x_{145}$) the  cokernel has rank 1, and on the Grassmannian it has rank 3.